# Determine whether the functional sequence is uniformly convergent.

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

The functional sequence is given by; $$f_n(x)=ne^{-(x-n)^2}$$
So far all I have got is $$f(x)= \lim_{n\to \infty} ne^{-(x-n)^2} = 0 $$
i.e. it is pointwise convergent to zero.
**Question**: Am I correct here and do I then use $ \vert f_n(x)-f(x)\vert\lt\epsilon$ to determine whether the convergence is uniform?

Comment: If you've got no idea as to where to start from, it could be helpful to just start from basic definitions (of uniform continuity in this case). It's fairly easy to see that $s_n=\sup_x |f_n(x)-f(x)|\ge n$ for each $n$ here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
f_n\left(n\right)=n
$$
Hence

$$\underset{x \in \mathbb{R}}{\text{sup}}\left|f_n\left(x\right)-f\left(x\right)\right| \geq n
$$
So it does not tend to $0$. There's no uniform convergence.